# Mount USB OTG to specific destination folder on Nexus 6

Tags: rooting, external-sd, mount, internal-sd, bind-mount

I have an app that looks for videos in a specific folder: “videos”. I'm trying to get my FAT flash drive to mount on the folder videos under `/sdcard` internal storage.

Nexus 6 (no SD card slot)
LineageOS 16
(Android 9)

Tried:

```
~$ su -mm
~# mount -o bind /mnt/sdcard/videos /mnt/media_rw/A064A9EB64A9C3FE
```

Did not work and editing the `fstab` file does not save after reboot.

Android `fstab` file:

```
# The filesystem that contains the filesystem checker binary (typically /system) cannot
# specify MF_CHECK, and must come before any filesystems that do specify MF_CHECK
#

# NOTE: /system partition is now early-mounted and the fstab entry is specified in device tree (duplicated below for recovery image purposes only):

#<src>                                              <mnt_point>     <type>  <mnt_flags and options>                                         <fs_mgr_flags>
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/system       /system         ext4    ro,barrier=1                                                    wait,recoveryonly
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/userdata     /data           ext4    rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,noauto_da_alloc,nobarrier               wait,check,formattable,latemount,encryptable=/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/metadata,reservedsize=128M
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/userdata     /data           f2fs    rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,inline_xattr                            wait,formattable,latemount,encryptable=/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/metadata,reservedsize=128M
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/cache        /cache          ext4    rw,noatime,nosuid,nodev,barrier=1,data=ordered                  wait,check,formattable
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/cache        /cache          f2fs    rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,inline_xattr                            wait,check,formattable
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/modem        /firmware       ext4    ro,barrier=1,context=u:object_r:firmware_file:s0                wait
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/persist      /persist        ext4    rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,barrier=1                               wait,check,notrim
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/boot         /boot           emmc    defaults                                                        defaults
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/recovery     /recovery       emmc    defaults                                                        defaults
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/misc         /misc           emmc    defaults                                                        defaults
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/modem        /modem          emmc    defaults                                                        defaults
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/mdm1m9kefs1  /mdm1m9kefs1    emmc    defaults                                                        defaults
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/mdm1m9kefs2  /mdm1m9kefs2    emmc    defaults                                                        defaults
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/mdm1m9kefs3  /mdm1m9kefs3    emmc    defaults                                                        defaults
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/sbl1         /sbl1           emmc    defaults                                                        defaults
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/tz           /tz             emmc    defaults                                                        defaults
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/rpm          /rpm            emmc    defaults                                                        defaults
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/sdi          /sdi            emmc    defaults                                                        defaults
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/aboot        /aboot          emmc    defaults                                                        defaults
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/versions     /versions       emmc    defaults                                                        defaults
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/logo         /logo           emmc    defaults                                                        defaults
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/frp          /persistent     emmc    defaults                                                        defaults
/devices/*/xhci-hcd.0.auto/usb*                     auto            auto    defaults                                                        voldmanaged=usb:auto
/dev/block/zram0                                    none            swap    defaults                                                        zramsize=536870912,notrim,max_comp_streams=4
```

Hard to find info on Android mounting system. These are what I have found:

- [How to bind-mount "data" and "obb" folders from external SD card in "/sdcard/Android"?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219386)
- [How can I make a symlink (or equivalent) inside /storage/emulated/0?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/203951)
- [Mount USB OTG to specific destination folder](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/62680)
- [Let's clear up the confusion regarding storage in Android once and for all, including adoptable storage in Marshmallow.](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/496sn3/lets_clear_up_the_confusion_regarding_storage_in)
- [How the Mount SD Card Android Process works](http://www.biemmeitalia.net/blog/how-mount-sd-card-android-works)

Comment: `mount` command takes source first, then the target. You are doing it inverse. It should be: `mount -o bind /mnt/media_rw/A064A9EB64A9C3FE /mnt/sdcard/videos`. But that won't work either because apps don't have direct access to USB OTG drives. Also there are mount namespaces involved. Explained here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218338/218526

Comment: ahh thanks for the tip. I forgot to say I changed to Global namespace in Magisk but it changes back on reboot. I'm typing it in direct from the device terminal. Is there anyway to get it to work? I am rooted

Comment: like somthing mount -o bind /mnt/media_rw/A064A9EB64A9C3FE /mnt/storage/extSdCard//videos ? even tho I don't have a real ext sdcard